# Need Help in completing the contact form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am making a contact form with the following code

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$maker = $_POST['maker'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$headers = 'From: me <reply@locallockman.com>';
$thankyou = "thankyou.html"; // thank you page
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['maker']) && isset($_POST['model']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
    $type = $_POST['service'];
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];

    $model = $_POST['model'];

    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(empty($phone)){
        echo 'Please fill all fields.';
    }
    else{
        if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
        header('Location: thankyou.html');

        }
        else{
            echo 'There was an error sending email/s.';
        }
    }

}

?>
```

It works perfectly, but i want text field to be disabled when user selects another option. I am using javascript for that.This is the code

```
 <script>
    function findselected(){
var state = document.getElementById('#type');
var notus = document.getElementById('#model');
var year = document.getElementById('#year');
var maker = document.getElementById('#maker');
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? notus.disabled = false : notus.disabled =  true;
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? year.disabled = false : year.disabled =  true;
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? maker.disabled = false : maker.disabled =  true;
}
</script>
```

Here is the html code

```
<select name="service" id="type" onchange="findselected()">
    <option value="Not Selected">Select Service Type</option>
    <option value="Residential Service">Residential Service</option>
    <option value="Commercial Service">Commercial Service</option>
    <option value="Industrial Service">Industrial Service</option>
    <option value="24/7 or Emergency Service">24/7 or Emergency Service</option>
    <option value="Automotive Service">Automotive Service</option>
    </select>
<select name="maker" id="maker" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left:36px;" autocomplete="on">
      <option value="Not Selected" selected="selected" ><strong>Select Car Make</strong></option>
      <option value="Acura" >Acura</option>
      <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
      <option value="Buick">Buick</option>
      <option value="Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
      <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
      <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
      <option value="Daewoo">Daewoo</option>
      <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
      <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="General Motors">General Motors</option>
      <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
      <option value="Hummer">Hummer</option>
      <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
      <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
      <option value="Infinity">Infinity</option>
      <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
      <option value="Jeep">Jeep</option>
      <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
      <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
      <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes Benz</option>
      <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
      <option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>
      <option value="Mini">Mini</option>
      <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
      <option value="NISSAN">NISSAN</option>
      <option value="Plymouth">Plymouth</option>
      <option value="Pontiac">Pontiac</option>
      <option value="Porche">Porche</option>
      <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="Saturn">Saturn</option>
      <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
      <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
      <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
      <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="model" id="model" style="margin-left:83px;" class="text-box" autocomplete="on" disabled="disabled" value=" "/><br /><br />
        Model Year:
        <input type="text" name="year" id="year" value=" " disabled="disabled" style="margin-left:73px;" class="text-box" autocomplete="on"/>
```

Here is the complete code. I want when i select Any other option then "Automotive Service" in  tag, the fields with name "year", "model" and list box with name "maker" should be disabled and blank values should be sent to e-mail.

This works for me but when I run it, but then form does not work. When I choose Automotive Service the form works and text fields 'year' and 'model gets enabled and form works. But when i choose any other option from the field and the text fields gets disabled, then form does not work, how can I fix it, please help.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS was not correct. You cannot use `#` in `getElementById('#type')` on native Javascript (I think you might be confused with jQuery)

Here is the correct code,

```
  function findselected(){
    var state = document.getElementById('type');
    var notus = document.getElementById('model');
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var maker = document.getElementById('maker');
    notus.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ? false : true;
    year.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ? false : true;
    maker.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ?  false : true;
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F2PLF/1/

**Update:**
You may have to rewrite the `if` condition in your php code for `$_POST['maker']`, `$_POST['model']` and `$_POST['year']`.When they are disabled, no value will be sent to server. so can either remove those from the `if` condition, like this

`if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['message'])){`

Or you may have to re-write your `if` condition based on the selected values from the drop-down `<select>`

Comment: I used this as well, but when the fields are disabled, the form does not work.

Comment: I am new in PHP, so doesn't really know how can i do that. Can you please help me in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

When form elements are `disabled` they will not be sent, so they will not be available in `$_POST`. So this line -

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['maker']) && isset($_POST['model']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['message']))
```

will fail.

You can either use `read-only`, remove the `disabled` on submit, or change your `if(isset())...`

see - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Answer (score 0):

to get the empty values in $_POST[] array [this post can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170396/how-do-i-make-radio-buttons-select-boxes-and-checkboxes-required-fields-in-a-f/14170488#14170488)

try to use simple if loop in **js**

like:

```
function findselected(){

if(document.getElementById("type").value=="Automated Service")
    {
    notus.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ? false : true;
        year.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ? false : true;
        maker.disabled = (state.value == "Automotive Service") ?  false : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working. When i choose "Automative", the fields do not get enabled.