# My javascript contact form doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to use javascript to disbale fields when an option is select from list box. But when the fields are disabled, form does not work.

I am making a contact form with this PHP code

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$maker = $_POST['maker'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$headers = 'From: me <reply@locallockman.com>';
$thankyou = "thankyou.html"; // thank you page
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['maker']) && isset($_POST['model']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
    $type = $_POST['service'];
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];

    $model = $_POST['model'];

    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(empty($phone)){
        echo 'Please fill all fields.';
    }
    else{
        if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
        header('Location: thankyou.html');

        }
        else{
            echo 'There was an error sending email/s.';
        }
    }

}

?>
```

This is the javascript that I am using to disable and enable the fields.

```
 <script>
    function findselected(){
var state = document.getElementById('type');
var notus = document.getElementById('model');
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var maker = document.getElementById('maker');
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? notus.disabled = false : notus.disabled =  true;
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? year.disabled = false : year.disabled =  true;
(state.value == "Automotive Service")? maker.disabled = false : maker.disabled =  true;
}
</script>
```

Now if don't use javascript this form works. But when i use this javascript form does not work.

Here is the HTML code of the form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  Customer Name :
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="text-box" autocomplete="on" />

    Contact No. :
    <input type="number" name="phone" class="text-box" autocomplete="on"/><br /><br />
    E-mail:
    <input type="email" name="e_mail" class="text-box" autocomplete="on"/><br /><br />
    Service Type:
    <select name="service" id="type" onchange="findselected()">
    <option value="Not Selected">Select Service Type</option>
    <option value="Residential Service">Residential Service</option>
    <option value="Commercial Service">Commercial Service</option>
    <option value="Industrial Service">Industrial Service</option>
    <option value="24/7 or Emergency Service">24/7 or Emergency Service</option>
    <option value="Automotive Service">Automotive Service</option>
    </select>


    Car Make:
    <select name="maker" id="maker" autocomplete="on">
      <option value="Not Selected" selected="selected" ><strong>Select Car Make</strong></option>
      <option value="Acura" >Acura</option>
      <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
      <option value="Buick">Buick</option>
      <option value="Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
      <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
      <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
      <option value="Daewoo">Daewoo</option>
      <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
      <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="General Motors">General Motors</option>
      <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
      <option value="Hummer">Hummer</option>
      <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
      <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
      <option value="Infinity">Infinity</option>
      <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
      <option value="Jeep">Jeep</option>
      <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
      <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
      <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes Benz</option>
      <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
      <option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>
      <option value="Mini">Mini</option>
      <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
      <option value="NISSAN">NISSAN</option>
      <option value="Plymouth">Plymouth</option>
      <option value="Pontiac">Pontiac</option>
      <option value="Porche">Porche</option>
      <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="Saturn">Saturn</option>
      <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
      <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
      <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
      <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    </select>

    Car Model:
    <input type="text" name="model" id="model" class="text-box" autocomplete="on"  disabled="disabled" value=" "/>
    Model Year:
    <input type="text" name="year" id="year" value=" " disabled="disabled" class="text-box" autocomplete="on"/>

Service Required:
        <textarea name="message" class="text-area" autocomplete="on"></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value=" " class="submit"/>
      </p>
    </form>
```

When I select any option other than "Automotive Service" from the list box, the fields "Car-Make", "Car Model" and "Model Year" gets disabled. But when I run the form, it does not work.

1. When I choose "Automotive Service" from list box, it does work.
2. But when I choose other options, fields are disabled but form does not work.

Comment: Dont kill yourself, relax and keep cool. Someone will surely guide you in right direction

Comment: Its getting really very difficult for me. Desperately need someone who can take me out of it.

Comment: "but form does not work." means it does not submit?

Comment: Yes right. It does not submit. I have inserted my e-mail id, where the e-mail should be sent. But i get nothing, but a blank page when i run it on my domain.

Comment: Look for what Cerbrus has suggested, that is the reason you are not getting email

Comment: You've asked this identical question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209491/need-help-in-completing-the-contact-form; Did you not get the answer you needed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `if`:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail'])...
```

If the fields are disabled, the data will not be sent, so the `if` will not pass.
(Since `$_POST['phone']` is not set, if the related field is disabled)

You'll have to check for the `$_POST` values individually.

---

As fas as I can see, you can leave these be:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['message']){
```

But these values can be "not set":

```
$_POST['model']
$_POST['year']
$_POST['maker']
```

So, remove those 3 `$_POST` variables out of your `if`, like the example above, then replace:

```
$maker = $_POST['maker'];

$model = $_POST['model'];

$year = $_POST['year'];
```

With:

```
$maker = $model = $year = 'Not Set'; // Or just use a empty string: '';
if(isset($_POST['maker'])){
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];
}
if(isset($_POST['model'])){
    $model = $_POST['model'];
}
if(isset($_POST['year'])){
    $year = $_POST['year'];
}
```

(Technically, those if's aren't necessary, but they're nice if you want a default "Not set" value in the variables)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i do that? As i said i am new in PHP, so i have learned only this thing to make a form, don't know anything more than this. Please help!!

Comment: He means to say that if your fields are disabled then your php does not have to check for them for being set. In simple words you can remove the checks for isset($_POST['maker']) && isset($_POST['model']) && isset($_POST['year']) from your PHP and it will work even if those are disabled

Comment: @Sam: Edited in a option on how to deal with this.

Comment: where should i place this code? 

before the if(empty($phone)) ??

Comment: Yes. And remove the `$maker = $_POST['maker'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$year = $_POST['year'];` you have in there.

Comment: The form is working. :) You save my life indeed friend.

 It would not have been possible for me to do this without you. I have no words to thank you. You are just like an angel for me, that god has sent to me.

Thankyou so much for your help!! I really appreciate it.

Thanks again.:)

Comment: Hehe, accepting my answer is praise enough ^_^ Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but the first PHP part of your question can be greatly simplified:

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$maker = $_POST['maker'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$headers = 'From: me <reply@locallockman.com>';
$thankyou = "thankyou.html"; // thank you page
if($fname && $phone && $e_mail && $service && $maker && $model && $year && $message){

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
    header('Location: thankyou.html');

    }
    else{
        echo 'There was an error sending emails.';
    }

}

?>
```

PHP treats empty or null variables as "false" so you don't have to check the `$_POST` variables again, after you assign them to your local variables. I don't see where you create `$to` or `$body`, though, so that's a problem.